# MIME type conflict with TYPO3 compressed CSS and JS resources

Tags: apache, typo3, mime-types, typo3-10.x

I am rather new to TYPO3. Recently I noticed some very weird behavior in my installation: Some CSS-files in the directory `typo3temp/assets/compressed` got the MIME-type `text/html` instead of the expected `text/css`. Therefore my browser received a 403 Forbidden status code from the webserver for these resources. That resulted in some parts of the backend being shown without styling.

I tried clearing all caches and deleting the `typo3temp/assets/compressed` directory, however now all the stuff in there (CSS and JS) is served with MIME-type `text/html`. Getting the backend without JavaScript means, that I am now basically locked out of the backend. I can however still reach and use the install tool.

Do you have any ideas how this might happen and how to fix it?

Some details of my setup:

- TYPO3 v10.4.13 (recently updated from 10.4.9)
- Apache web server (I don't have access to its config and have to rely on .htaccess files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to set

```
TYPO3_CONF_VARS/FE/compressionLevel=0
TYPO3_CONF_VARS/BE/compressionLevel=0
```

in order not have these kind of problems. The problem is that this compression creates compressed files but relies on webserver configuration in order to deliver them as `text/css` and NOT applying the default webserver's transport compression to them (or they could end up double-compressed and you might not even easily notice - some browsers can deal with that, others not).

It is a kind of micro-optimization that sounded useful in times when we avoided https:// because of the processing overhead...

Here's some docs (the first statement is outdated in my oppinion): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-skinning/master/en-us/BackendCssApi/CssCompression/Index.html

Comment: That might be a part of the problem, as I once set these to 5. I have the compression level back on 0 now and the problem still persists. The files in typo3temp/assets/compressed sill follow the patterns merged-<some-numbers>.css and require-<some-numbers>.js (without the additional .gzip). Is that the expected pattern? I ask because it is different in my still functional local installation which is in debug mode. There the file name pattern is e.g. bootstrap.min-<some-numbers>.css, i.e. the different CSS and JS resources aren't merged into a single file.

Comment: Have you cleared caches? Yes, the pattern looks usual for TypoScript `config.concatenateJS`/`compressJS` https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#compressjs . I can't say much about it because I don't use those, either...

Comment: I cleared caches and removed temporary files but I still get 403 codes and the html MIME type for the backend CSS and JS. I think the problem is that the temporary files in typo3temp shoudn't be used for the backend in the first place. Instead the files in typo3/sysext/** should be used. At least that is how it is in my local installation. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: I would ignore the wrong mime type for now (it's probably a 403 error page). Also ignore why it is loaded from /typo3temp. Rather track down the 403. That could be due to wrong file permissions for example.

Comment: Good suggestion. Indeed the problem turned out to be misconfigured file and folder creation permission masks, which prevented the server from accessing the cached files. Thanks a lot for your help.